# Git: should merged branch be always deleted?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a question related to git merge workflow.

When we merge one branch to another, AFAIK two things may happen: either a single commit would be created on the destination branch (in non fast-forward case) or commits from the merged branch will be applied "on top of" commits on the destination branch.

I am especially interested in the fist case. While in the second case all history of changes is transfered to the destination branch, in the first case, the history is "squashed" into a single commit. As a result, if we remove the merged branch, we have only a single commit incorporating all the changes from the branch.
On the other hand, if it happens that the merged branch was originated from the destination branch, AFAIK, every rebase of the destination branch would require rebase of the merged branch to keep them in-sync.

My question is: should we always delete merged branches or there is a way to keep the merged branch and prevent from rebasing it every time it's "root" branch is rebased?

Rationale for keeping the merged branch is that in such case we have insight into detailed history of changes done on that branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use the `--squash` option in the `git merge` call, the branch information of the merged branch will be preserved. The newly created *merge* commit simply has two (or more, in case of an octopus merge) parent commits instead of a single one. The first parent corresponds to the branch you merged into, the other parents represent the branches that were merged.

You can visualize this using e.g. the `gitk` tool, or by e.g. using

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph --decorate
```

So, in case of a normal merge (non-squash, no matter whether fast or non-fast forward), you can easily keep your original branch and continue developing with it. If you squashed, a future non-squash merge will be potentially very confusing for the posterity, so it might be a good idea to use `git reset --hard` on it or `git rebase` in case you already have new changes.

Comment: Thank you! Could you possibly recommend any strategy for rebases in case when merged branches are kept? Is there any way to prevent from rebasing merged branches along with branches that they are derived from?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you want... Rebasing essentially applies a patch sequence to a different starting point, that's all. I think the [`git-rebase(1)`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) explains this nicely.

Comment: I was thinking about the case when we have some "base" branch, from which we derive "work" branch and then, after some time, we merge the "work" branch back to the "base" in non fast-forward manner. In that case, AFAIK, every time "base" is rebased to .e.g. upstream, that would require rebasing the "work" branch too, even though, we do not do any further work on that branch and it has been merged to the "base" branch. I was wondering if there is any way to prevent from this necessity of doing rebases of the "work" branch if we want to keep it after the merge.

Comment: No, you can't do that automatically. I'm not sure whether [`TopGit`](http://repo.or.cz/w/topgit.git) helps here. [`StackedGit`](http://www.procode.org/stgit) certainly allows you to rebase very easily, but then, branches maintained with it are not well suited for merging in the first place...

Comment: I think you might be using rebasing wrong. You should never rebase anything that has been pushed or in another way shared outside your local repository. All other clones will be in a very confused state if you do. http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html#The-Perils-of-Rebasing

Answer (score 1):

When you merge you have a choice of squashing it or to leave it as it is.

I would say that if you squash it just go a head and delete the branch as it has clearly done it's part after it was squashed.

If you leave the branch intact (no squashing) you can leave it and reuse it if you need.

Generally I would only squash commits if the history is useless or even wrong. I've done development where commits fail to build that where fixed later. Those commits should be squashed away before the merge.

Comment: Thank you! Actually what I've recently done was to merge branch in non fast-forward manner (even though it would normally be merged as fast-forward) because I wanted to have compiling/working state on the destination branch while being able to see commits done on the merged branch.

Comment: Tomek, Your right, I always use a --no-ff with my merges. Actually there's a way to set --no-ff in your global settings so you never use a fast-forward. I like to see the lane changes in the past too.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work, we use [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) as our workflow model. When we implement a change we create a feature branch and put in an empty commit to describe the branch.

```
git checkout -b feature1
git commit --allow-empty -m "Create branch to add a menu."
```

When we're done with this work, or hit a good stopping point, we merge in the feature branch (non-fast-forward) and delete the feature branch.

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff feature1
git branch -d feature1
```

The branch history is still retained as a "lane change" under gitk. This allows us good visibility in what was changed for that feature, but avoids cluttering up the list of branches we have.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about this "lane change" feature of gitk.